# How to get the react-datetime date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I am using the react-datetime and moment.

How can I use the onChange for get the changed date? and return the string

```
this.state={ date: "2019-01-01" }

<DateTime 
    defaultValue={this.state.date}
    timeFormat={false}
    onChange={onChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a handler for onChange, something like this:

```
handleChange=(value)=>{
   //value is the changed value
  this.setState({date: value})
}

<DateTime 
    defaultValue={this.state.date}
    timeFormat={false}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Then value is the changed value. Handle change function is called everytime the datetime calls onChange.